# Adding Reporting Capabilities to MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, reporting, reportviewer, report

**Background**: I currently have a Web Forms, ASP.NET 3.5/C# application which I'm interested in converting to MVC 2. It's a relatively tiny app so the exercise shouldn't take too long. The two primary functions the appliction does is allow users to

1) view and enter their data - metrics

2) view output reports of this data aggreggated at a higher level.

This second point is of concern to me as my first impression of MVC is that most of the reporting tools do not work with it. I'm currently using ReportViewer for 2) but I read here and on other sites that configuring it to work with MVC is a pain.

Are there any other types of Reporting capabilities that I could use with MVC 2? Are there some that work "out of the box"?

Or in your experience of using MVC 2, would it be easier to put together your own report? My requirement is to make a report that is similar to ReportViewer's Matrix style, with a few merged cells and a drill down by two levels. Don't know if that's way too complicated to do with MVC from scratch or not.

**EDIT**: Bonus if you know of any other Reporting add-ons that work with MVC besdies ReportViewer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used the RDLC local reports to do this but I don't use the report viewer (even in webforms).  [I always stream the report straight to PDF](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/03/02/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview.aspx).  This works great in MVC as well since in this case I am avoiding the report viewer control.

This [tutorial/post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/11/25/rendering-an-rdlc-directly-to-the-response-stream-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) shows how to stream in MVC.

Comment: If you must use a pre-processed report then do it this way - dump it direct to the response.

Answer (score 1):

Please check my tutorial about reportviewer and mvc2 -> [How to use ReportViewer 2010 in MVC.NET 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577118/how-to-use-reportviewer-2010-in-mvc-net-2)

Hope it helps you